# FileHelpers quoted fields contains single quote?

Tags: csv, filehelpers

How to read FileHelpers quoted fields contains single quote?

Below is my csv records

```
"1","7" Screen","Mobile"
```

Model:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]

public class LineModel 
{

 [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]

 public string Id;

 [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]

 public string Details;

 [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]

 public string Device;

}
```

Getting error for above record:-**The field Details is quoted but the quoted char: " not is just before the separator (You can use [FieldTrim] to avoid this error)**

Answer (score 1):

`QuoteMode` does not work very well when you have ambiguous quotes in your input file.  Instead, you can remove the `[FieldQuoted]` attributes and handle the quotes in a custom converter.

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class LineModel
{
    [FieldConverter(typeof(MyQuotedFieldConverter))]
    public string Id;

    [FieldConverter(typeof(MyQuotedFieldConverter))]
    public string Details;

    [FieldConverter(typeof(MyQuotedFieldConverter))]
    public string Device;
}

public class MyQuotedFieldConverter : ConverterBase
{
    public override object StringToField(string from)
    {
        // If the field starts and ends with a double quote
        if (from.StartsWith("\"") && from.EndsWith("\""))
        {
            // Remove the first and last character
            return from.Substring(1, from.Length - 1);
        }
        return from;
    }
}
```

Of course then you'll have trouble if you have "," within your fields.

```
"1","7, Screen","Mobile"
```

In which case, you have to pre-parse the record line to clean up the input by implementing the `INotifyRead` interface. Something like:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class LineModel : INotifyRead
{
    //... fields as before

    public void BeforeRead(BeforeReadEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RecordLine.Count(x => x == ',') > 3)
        {
            e.RecordLine = DetectAndReplaceEmbeddedDelimiters(e.RecordLine);
        }
    }

    public void AfterRead(AfterReadEventArgs e)
    {                
    }
}
```

Another approach to consider the reverse: use the custom converter to add quotes to every field and remove/replace embedded quotes. Then use `QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted`.